# committing on github

Tags: github, repository, commit

I cloned a repository into my machine. Changed a file. Then committed it.

```
BackchannelApplication-1 git:(master) ✗ git commit
[master c5c7f47] Updating integration test
 1 files changed, 13 insertions(+), 10 deletions(-)
➜  BackchannelApplication-1 git:(master) git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

git log
commit c5c7f47b6f96042beef3cddc051f5a38923d279a
Author: Name <emailid>
Date:   Tue Oct 18 18:58:51 2011 -0400

    Updating integration test
```

On my machine I can see the file is changed but can't see the same on the github. Why so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After committing, you need to push the commits to the external repository (GitHub) with `git push`.

Answer (score 2):

You then need to push the change back to the origin.

```
// of the format: git push [alias] [branch]

git push origin master
```

When you committed, you committed your change only to the local repository on your machine.